# Keeping Values in the same place when I change the first column

Tags: excel, position

I‘m looking for a solution to a problem that should be quite simple.

I‘ve got data that looks like this:

```
A | 1
B | 2
C | 3
```

Now I want to paste a new list in the first column, but I want to keep the values in the second column in the same spot:

```
A | 1
B | 2
D | 
C | 3
```

How do I do this, preferably without using vba.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using `VLOOKUP`.

As shown in below image, keep you initial input data in column `D` and `E`

[image]

Apply the vlookup formula shown below, in column `B`, when you paste the new column in column `A` your column `B` will be updated as you need.

The formula is the combination of `if` and `VLOOKUP`, if `#NA` keep the cell empty else use `VLOOKUP`.

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,$D$2:$E$4,2,0)),"",VLOOKUP(A1,$D$2:$E$4,2,0))
```